# How do I install Microsoft Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I can't seem to find it in the SQL Server Enterprise 2008 installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it finally.  Start the SQL server Enterprise install.  Then on about the 7th page of the install it finally comes up with a selection list where you can choose to install BIDS. Wow, now that's "great design".

Comment: Were they supposed to assume that you wanted BIDS on the first screen? ;)